# Batch appending (set side by side horizontally) entire folder of images in pairs using imagemagick

Tags: batch, adobe-photoshop, imagemagick

I'm trying to figure out the correct command(s) to batch append (and output with a sequentially numbered (incremented) filename) an entire folder of PNG files, in pairs.

i.e. I have a folder of images:

9091.png
9092.png
9093.png
...
9520.png

and I'd like to merge each pair of images and output to a file (which is incrementally numbered - say 00001.png, 00002.png etc). So 9091.png and 9092.png would be paired and output. Then 9093.png and 9094.png would be paired and output, etc.

I've installed Imagemagick on Windows and I'm not getting the results I expect when running some commands I've found variously on the net. Any ideas if this is doable? I'd run an action in Photoshop to do this but it won't save incrementally for some reason.

Comment: What do you mean by "pair" do you mean 9091.png and 9092.png will be moved into a new folder? so every two followed pngs will be moved into a new folder?

Comment: Sorry, i mean that each pair (two consecutive files regardless of filename) of images in the folder  (there are about 400) is placed side by side horizontally and saved as a separate file with numerically incrementing filenames. The individual images are mostly square (photos of each side of a coin) so i need to save each consecutive pair of images to a separate single file where they are combined horizontally.

Comment: I think I've got what you search for, you want a method to check the image itself and get the other pair of that image and then move both images into a new folder. IF that what you mean, then it's beyond Batch capabilities. Batch cannot search within the image, and I can't think of a software can do this either. If they have certain filenames then you can use batch to move them. other than that, you have to do them manually.